# Ordering bookmarks c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, bookmarks

i have a template word file with 4 different bookmarks, i want to add them to the form.

```
foreach (Bookmark bookmark in WordDocument.Bookmarks)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bookmark.Name);                  
 }
```

But in the grid they are ordered by name, though i want them ordered by location, ive tried this construction:

```
var orderedBoomarks = WordDocument.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>()
                          .OrderBy(d => d.Start).ToList();
```

How can i use this variable and insert it to my grid?(I barely understand what means this construction). Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try the obvious _foreach(Bookmark bkm in orderedBookmarks)_ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!) this way is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var orderedBoomarks = WordDocument.Bookmarks.Cast<Bookmark>().OrderBy(d => d.Start);
foreach (var bookmark in orderedBoomarks)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bookmark.Name);
```